# Precompile ASP.NET Application after Installation

Tags: asp.net, inno-setup, aspnet-compiler, appcmd

I have an ASP.NET Application compiled into installation package using [INNO Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) installer. When I install an application to the dedicated server I want to [precompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx) the whole application so it runs smoothly when first user arrives.

The problem is that only thing I know is the installation path. But what I need is the virtual path of the application in IIS to run this command:

```
aspnet_compiler -v AppVirtualPath
```

In my case, the application already exists in IIS and is mapped to the installation directory. I've been trying use the [appcmd.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28WS.10%29.aspx) to get virtual path by physical path. No luck so far.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.